# Difference between horizontal and vertical microcode

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, processor, instructions

I know what are microcoded instructions in computer architecture and design but was confused between these two terminologies. Went through several articles but was unable to get the clarity.

Some of them said:

Horizontal Microcodes : In this types of code the micro code contains the control signal without any intermediary.

Vertical Microcodes :  In case of vertical micro code every action is encoded in density.

The terminologies are above my understanding and would appreciate a simpler explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode#Implementation) gives a good introduction.

Assume for the sake of simplicity that we have just two [MUX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer)s in the CPU data-path, say A and B.
And that each MUX is controlled by 4 bits.

A horizontal microcoded instruction would contain the select value for both MUXs A and B:

```
     4-bit   4-bit
     ______ _______
    |  A   |   B   |
     ¯¯¯¯¯¯ ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
       |       |
       |       |
    ___V_   ___V_
   |MUX A| |MUX B|
    ¯¯¯¯¯   ¯¯¯¯¯
```

The bits from the instruction are fed directly into the select lines of the two MUXs

A vertical microcoded instruction would instead make use of a DEMUX, a "meta-DEMUX", that is used to select which MUX to drive.

```
 1

 b
 i
 t  4-bit
 _ _______
|M|  SEL  |
 ¯ ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 |    | 4-bit DEMUX input
 |   _V_                          _______
 '->| D |  -- 4-bit output 0 --> | MUX A |
    | M |'                        ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
    | U |.                        _______
    | X |  -- 4-bit output 1 --> | MUX B |
     ¯¯¯                          ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

So there is an intermediary combinatoric circuit between the instruction signal bits and the driven components.

You can already see that vertical microcode has shorter instruction but a longer propagation time.

Comment: @AshishK Nothing, just a term I invented. It's a DEMUX not in the datapath :)

Comment: @MargaretBloom. Better explanation than wiki!!. one question, why would anyone use vertical? I cant see any winning, certainly the ops are smaller, but you need decoders which will add something to the die area.

Comment: @IsuruH Horizontal microcode doesn't work with pipelines, it drives all of the CPU control lines at once, where with pipelines different instructions use different parts of the CPU, and thus different sets of control lines at the same time. Vertical microcode can be processed in the pipeline like an ordinary instructions because they're are essentially the real instructions the CPU executes.